# Php form submit alert if less than 1min passed

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need some help with my php code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$now = date("H:i:s");
?>
<form method="post" name="update" action="update.php" />
<input type='text' name='fname' value=''> 
<input type='text' name='lname' value=''> 
<input type='text' name='email' value=''> 
...
<button type="submit" value="Submit"/> Submit </button>
</form>
```

What i need:
If someone clicks on button submit but it passed less than 1 min since start($now)
then it must appear an Alert "Check Info"(not another page or popup),
an alert like "Do you really want to leave the page?"

Comment: What you need is JS / jQuery, once php is loaded it's done.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: *Sorry.* " **what i need:..** work " we not do.

Answer (score 1):

I should not work for free... but I won't give you the full answer!!! Make an effort and fill in the right code <<< FILL >>> to get it to work!!!

```
<script src="<<<FILL>>>"></script>
<script>
    submitAllowed = false
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (<<<FILL>>>||confirm("Do you really want to leave")) {
            this.submit()
        }
    });
    function submitAttempt(){
        submitAllowed = true;
    }
    setTimeout(<<<FILL>>>, 60000);
</script>
```